# XSLT: Add a new node with a variable number of child elements based on the presence of other elements

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to add a new node with a variable number of child elements based on the existence of other elements elsewhere in the XML document.  Here's a simplified example of what I'm starting with:

**Input:**

```
<Parent>
    <FirstChild>
        <List>  
        <!--There could be an unlimited number of different Fruit elements in this list-->
            <Fruit A="Apples"/>
            <Fruit B="Bananas"/>
            <!--...-->
        </List>
    </FirstChild>
</Parent>
```

I need to add a new node (Parent/SecondChild), with child elements that are created based on the elements in the **List** node.  The output should look like this (minus my comments!):

**Desired Output:**

```
<Parent>
    <FirstChild>
        <List>
        <!--There could be an unlimited number of Fruit elements in this list-->
            <Fruit A="Apples"/>
            <Fruit B="Bananas"/>
            <!--...-->
        </List>
    </FirstChild>
    <SecondChild>
        <NewList>
        <!--A separate <NewFruit> element needs to be added below based on the existence of the <Fruit> elements in <List> above-->
            <NewFruit A="Apples"/>
            <NewFruit B="Bananas"/>
            <!--...-->
        </NewList>
    </SecondChild>
</Parent>
```

I know how to add the **SecondChild** node and sub-elements using a transformation like:

**Transform:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes" exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn xdt">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Parent">
    <Parent>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
        <SecondChild>
             <NewList>
             </NewList>
        </SecondChild>
    </Parent>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives the following output:

**Current Output:**

```
<Parent>
    <FirstChild>
        <List>
        <!--There could be an unlimited number of Fruit elements in this list-->
            <Fruit A="Apples"/>
            <Fruit B="Bananas"/>
            <!--...-->
        </List>
    </FirstChild>
    <SecondChild>
        <NewList>
        <!--HELP!-->
        </NewList>
    </SecondChild>
</Parent>
```

But I'm at a loss as to how to create the **NewFruit** child elements (where my HELP! comment is) dynamically based on the presence of the **Fruit** elements in the **FirstChild** node.  Any assistance would be extremely appreciated - I'm just not sure what direction to go in at this point.

**UPDATE:**

The response to my question worked for the XML I provided (thank you!), but it's not working for the XML I'm actually using (which I can't paste for confidentiality reasons).  The XML below exactly mimics the format I'm working with:

**Input:**

```
<Parent>
    <Level1>
        <Level2>
            <List>
            <!--There could be an unlimited number of different Fruit elements in this list-->
                <Fruit A="Apples"/>
                <Fruit B="Bananas"/>
            </List>
        </Level2>
        <NewLevel2>
        </NewLevel2>
    </Level1>
</Parent>
```

I need to add a new node (Parent/Level1/NewLevel2/NewNode), with some child elements that are created based on the elements in the **List** node.  The output should look like this:

**Desired Output:**

```
<Parent>
    <Level1>
        <Level2>
            <List>
            <!--There could be an unlimited number of Fruit elements in this list-->
                <Fruit A="Apples"/>
                <Fruit B="Bananas"/>
            </List>
        </Level2>
        <NewLevel2>
            <NewNode>
                <NewChildNode>
                    <NewChildNode1/>
                    <NewList>
                    <!--A separate <NewFruit> element needs to be added below based on the existence of the <Fruit> elements in <List> above-->
                        <NewFruit A="Apples"/>
                        <NewFruit B="Bananas"/>
                    </NewList>
                </NewChildNode>
            </NewNode>
        </NewLevel2>
    </Level1>
</Parent>
```

This is the XSLT I'm using:

**Transform:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes" exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn xdt">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="NewLevel2">
    <NewLevel2>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
        <NewNode>
            <NewChildNode>
                <NewChildNode1/>
                <NewList>
                    <xsl:for-each select="*/List/Fruit">
                        <NewFruit>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                        </NewFruit>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </NewList>
            </NewChildNode>
        </NewNode>
    </NewLevel2>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives the following output:

**Current Output:**

```
<Parent>
    <Level1>
        <Level2>
            <List>
            <!--There could be an unlimited number of different Fruit elements in this list-->
                <Fruit A="Apples"/>
                <Fruit B="Bananas"/>
            </List>
        </Level2>
        <NewLevel2>
            <NewNode>
                <NewChildNode>
                    <NewChildNode1/>
                    <NewList/>
                </NewChildNode>
            </NewNode>
        </NewLevel2>
    </Level1>
</Parent>
```

So the NewList element is empty - the NewFruit child nodes aren't being created for some reason.  However, I don't understand why this doesn't work when the original XML I posted did transform correctly?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You say "based on the existence of other elements elsewhere in the XML document". Where exactly is that "elsewhere"? I see only one list in your source XML. What - if anything - should be difference between the two lists in the output?

Comment: (after your edit) I still don't understand your question. Are you just trying to duplicate the same list in two places of the output, or should there be any difference between the two?

Comment: Note that there is no `NewLevel2` element in your input, so `<xsl:template match="NewLevel2">` does not match anything, and consequently does not do anything either. **So your current output is NOT what you say it is.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust your XSLT as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
     xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
     xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes"
     exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn xdt">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" 
     omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Parent">
    <Parent>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
        <SecondChild>
          <NewList>
            <xsl:for-each select="*/List/Fruit">
              <NewFruit>
                 <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
              </NewFruit>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </NewList>
        </SecondChild>
    </Parent>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<Parent>
   <FirstChild>
      <List>  
         <Fruit A="Apples"/>
         <Fruit B="Bananas"/>
         <!--...-->
      </List>
   </FirstChild>
   <SecondChild>
      <NewList>
         <NewFruit A="Apples"/>
         <NewFruit B="Bananas"/>
      </NewList>
   </SecondChild>
</Parent>
```

**Update:** As you updated your question (input XML as well as desired output), following adjusted XSLT provides the new desired output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
   xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
   xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes" 
   exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn xdt">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" 
     omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Parent">
<Parent>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
</Parent>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="NewLevel2">
<NewLevel2>
  <NewNode>
    <NewChildNode>
       <NewChildNode1/>
         <NewList>
            <xsl:for-each select="//Parent//List/Fruit">
               <NewFruit>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
               </NewFruit>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </NewList>
     </NewChildNode>
  </NewNode>
</NewLevel2>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Input:**

```
<Parent>
  <Level1>
    <Level2>
        <List>
            <Fruit A="Apples"/>
            <Fruit B="Bananas"/>
        </List>
    </Level2>
    <NewLevel2>
    </NewLevel2>
</Level1>
</Parent>
```

**XML Output:**

```
<Parent>
   <Level1>
        <Level2>
            <List>
                <Fruit A="Apples"/>
                <Fruit B="Bananas"/>
            </List>
        </Level2>
        <NewLevel2>
         <NewNode>
            <NewChildNode>
               <NewChildNode1/>
               <NewList>
                  <NewFruit A="Apples"/>
                  <NewFruit B="Bananas"/>
               </NewList>
            </NewChildNode>
         </NewNode>
      </NewLevel2>
    </Level1>
</Parent>
```

As already mentioned as comment by michael.hor257k, your template matching `NewLevel2` won't generate any output as `NewLevel2` is just an empty element in your input XML. So to get the desired output the XSLT has only to be adjusted to have a template matching the empty `NewLevel2` that generates the output for `NewLevel2` not for the current node of this template (which is empty), but for the  list of fruits from the root - `<xsl:for-each select="//Parent//List/Fruit">`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This solution did work perfectly for the XML I provided, but when I tried it on my actual XML, it didn't transform correctly.  So I made an exact copy of the format of my XML and pasted the update in my original question, if you wouldn't mind taking another look?  Again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @lcf0285 Glad that I was able to help you. I've just updated my answer for the updated question.